# iOS 14 widget intents

Tags: swift, widget, ios14, sirikit, widgetkit

I have a widget with a `.intentdefinition` file set up, and I can select from my enum when running my widget, but I'm not sure how to use this information in the code.

What I want to be able to do is run different code in `getTimeline` based on what the user selects in the widget settings.

If anyone could help, that'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know what code I have to use to read the data from my intents. That's my question.

Answer (score 4):

To create a *configurable* widget you need to use `IntentConfiguration` and `IntentTimelineProvider`. This will allow you to access intent parameters which you can later use in the `getTimeline` function.

1. In your Widget you need to use `IntentConfiguration` (instead of `StaticConfiguration`) and select which intent to use (`intent` parameter):

```
struct IntentWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "IntentWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: CustomIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Intent Widget")
        .description("Intent Widget")
    }
}
```

2. Conform your Provider to `IntentTimelineProvider` (instead of `TimelineProvider`). Then you'd be able to use your intent in the `getSnapshot` and `getTimeline` methods:

```
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: CustomIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> Void) {
        completion(SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: CustomIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
        // here you can access your intent configuration
        // let selectedItem = configuration.selectedItem
        ...
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

---

Useful links:

- [Creating a Widget Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension)
- [Making a Configurable Widget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget)

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples#intent-widget) with different Widget examples including the Intent Widget.</sub>